# AWS sam sync... No such command

Tags: amazon-web-services

Im following the AWS [workshop for multi tenant on Serverless](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/b0c6ad36-0a4b-45d8-856b-8a64f0ac76bb/en-US/lab2/34-deploy-lab2)...
All works fine, but when trying to do

> cd ~/environment/aws-serverless-saas-workshop/Lab2/server
> echo Y | sam sync --stack-name serverless-saas --code --resource-id LambdaFunctions/CreateUserFunction --resource-id LambdaFunctions/RegisterTenantFunction --resource-id LambdaFunctions/GetTenantFunction -u

I get...

```
Error: No such command 'sync'.
```

same if I try just

```
sam sync
```

Im running on the cloud9 IDE if that makes any difference, thanks

Comment: odd, since `sam sync` [is a valid command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-sync.html)

Comment: what do you get if you type `sam --version` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error Error: No such command 'sync' appears, your installation of dbx is likely out of date. To fix this, run pip install --upgrade dbx== or python -m pip install --upgrade dbx==version , where  is the latest version of dbx